# List comprehension in python with multiple loops and if statements

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have to print a list of ordered pairs where x+y+z != n. The code doesn't seem to be working

```
def main():
    x = int(input())
    y = int(input())
    z = int(input())
    n = int(input())
    result = [[i,j,k] for i in range(0,x+1) for j in range(0,y+1) for k in range(0,z+1) if (x+y+z) != n]
    print(result)
```

Input:

```
1
1
1
2
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

I shouldn't be getting the ordered pairs [0,1,1] , [1,0,1], [1,1,0].

Please correct me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you meant `i+j+k != n`, btw never heard of itertools ?

Comment: The itertools solution `[i for i in itertools.product(range(x+1), range(y+1), range(z+1)) if sum(i) != n]`

Answer (score 4):

You mixed the list comprehension variables with the inputs from the user.

Replace:

```
if (x+y+z) != n
```

with

```
if (i+j+k) != n
```

Comment: @Raman You might consider using `itertools.product` to replace the nested loops

Answer (score -1):

One liners are great, but they can confuse me, so I will expand your code

```
    result = []
    for i in range(0, x+1):
        for j in range(0, y+1):
            for k in range(0, z+1):
                if (i+k+j)!=n:
                    result.append([i,k,j])
```

And it works for me